# Points not displaying on qgis2web when using point displacement

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I'm working with a point dataset on QGIS, and some points have the same coordinates. I changed the symbology to point displacement, which looks and works perfectly on the project window, but none of the points show up when I try to create a web map with the qgis2web plugin. The points do display on the web map when I am using single symbols, but I need to be able to differentiate between overlapping points. Does anyone have a solution to this?

And if it's not possible to use point displacement on a qgis2web map, is there another plugin or method to create a web map that could work for me?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Tick the "Cluster" checkbox.

When you export to OpenLayers you'll get a basic point symbol with the number of points:

[image]

When you export to Leaflet you'll get a point symbol with the number of points that expands when clicked on:

[image]